# fail to use streaming in http2 in golang

Tags: go, streaming, http2

How to reuse http2 stream in golang?

Hi all, recently I tried many ways to reuse a stream to send http2 data but failed, and I didn't find many related solutions in http2, can anyone give me some hints or demos?

```
client := http.Client{

        Transport: &http2.Transport{
            DialTLS: func(network, addr string, cfg *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {
                return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, time.Second)
            },
                AllowHTTP: true,
        },
    }

    resp, err := client.Get(path)
```

I tried to use resp as client and write to this resp to send data to server. Is it right way to do it?

Comment: maybe should you establish a websocket instead.

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP/2 streams are short lived, and correspond to a request/response exchange. In effect the end of the response closes the stream. Issuing another request via `client.Get` will automatically open a new stream on the connection, if the underlying connection is using HTTP/2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can i use the resp got from ```client.Get``` to send data to the server? If yes, how?

Comment: You can't use `resp` to send data to the server, unless i'm missing something about your question. Could you expand on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I want to open a stream to the server and send data to server via this stream, so that when some data comes to me, I can process it and send it to server using this stream. currently I use ```func (c *Client) Post(url, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *Response, err error)```, and for the third argument, I implement my own Reader function. Previously I used ```bytes.NewBuffer``` function but it gives me error like unexpected EOF. I want to know what's the right way to implement this function?